# Ramsey-like property with order condition

Tags: co.combinatorics, set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals, ramsey-theory

I wonder if there are regular cardinals $\lambda$ and $\kappa$ such that $\kappa < \lambda \leq 2^\kappa$ and such that, consistently, the following holds:

Let $c: [\lambda]^2 \to \kappa$ be such that for $\alpha < \beta < \gamma$, we have  $c(\alpha, \gamma) \leq \max \lbrace c(\alpha, \beta) , c(\beta, \gamma) \rbrace$. The there is a cofinal $H \subseteq \lambda$ such that $range(c \restriction [H]^2) \subseteq \eta$ for some $\eta < \kappa$.

Now, the second part is obviously true, even without the max condition, in case $\lambda $ is weakly compact, but then we lose $\lambda \leq 2^\kappa$ since $\lambda$ is strong limit.

I am particularly interested in the case where $\kappa = \aleph_0$, or more generally a regular cardinal.

Comment: There is a counterexample (assuming the axiom of choice of course) in case $\kappa=\aleph_0$ and $\lambda=\aleph_1$. I suppose that you already know this, and it's not worth posting as a partial answer, but it might be worth mentioning in the question.

Comment: Counterexample for $\kappa=\aleph_0$, $\lambda=\aleph_1$. For each $\beta\in\omega_1$ choose an injection $f_\beta:\beta\to\omega$. For $n\in\omega$ let $\lt_n$ be the transitive closure of  the relation $\{(\alpha,\beta):f_\beta(\alpha)\le n\}$. For $\alpha\lt\beta\lt\omega_1$ let $c(\{\alpha,\beta\})=\min\{n:\alpha\lt_n\beta\}$. If $H\subseteq\omega_1$ and $c\restriction[H]^2$ has finite range, then $H$ has order type $\le\omega$.

Comment: By the way, it might be more natural to describe the conditions on the "coloring" $c$ by saying that the natural well-ordering of $\lambda$ is expressed as the union of a $\kappa$-chain of partial orderings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A coloring $c:[\kappa]^2\rightarrow\theta$ is *subadditive of the first kind* if for all $\alpha<\beta<\gamma<\kappa$, $c(\alpha,\gamma)\le\max\{c(\alpha,\beta),c(\beta,\gamma)\}$. It is *subadditive of the second kind* if for all $\alpha<\beta<\gamma<\kappa$, $c(\alpha,\beta)\le\max\{c(\alpha,\gamma),c(\beta,\gamma)\}$. The combination of both is  called *subadditive*, and is the subject matter of the following paper: http://www.assafrinot.com/paper/36

The Ramsey-theoretic results you are after may be found as Lemma 3.38(2), Corollary 3.42(2), and Theorem 3.45(2) of the above paper. In particular, assuming PFA, for every regular cardinal $\kappa>2^{\aleph_0}$ that is not the successor of a singular cardinal of countable cofinality, every coloring $c:[\kappa]^2\rightarrow\omega$ that is subadditive of the first kind admits a cofinal subset $A\subseteq\kappa$ such that $c``[A]^2$ is finite.